# Why my account is still accessable after I remove the permission for the application?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to my first google drive application and found a problem about the permission setting.
My application works on Android (ICS) and uses Google Play Service auth2.0 function to get the access token.

When the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() function was called for the first time in my application, I got a message which requested the access permission to my google account. And I could access the files on my google drive after accepting the permission request.

Once the application is permitted, it is able to get an access token whenever it needs without confirming with the user. However, the application can still get an available token to access my google account even after I remove the access permission in my google account setting. I removed the permission a week ago and the application still can upload file to my account. It doesn't ask for the access permission any more.

What should I do to "completely" remove the access permission for my application?